# Efficiently Querying two large dictionaries stored as pickle files

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I have two large pickle files. Both of them have a one dictionary stored in them. I can not load both pickle files at the same time in to the memory, however, I want to merge the dictionaries stored in them and query on this merged dictionary. Is it possible to do this? See following snippets to get more insights in my query.

```
f1 = open('d1.pickle', 'rb')
d1 = pickle.load(f1)

# However, I can not load a second dictionary as follows in the same program
# because of memory limits

f2 = open('d2.pickle', 'rb')
d2 = pickle.load(f2)

f3 = open('d_final.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump({*d1, *d2}, f3)
```

UPDATE : 
I somehow want to do a faster querying on both of these dictionaries. One of my approach was to store both of these dictionaries in a single tsv file and then store the line offsets as indices of keys. Using these offsets, we can seek in that file position and get the value. But this seems a far slower than querying on the dictionary. See following for my attempt. **Can anyone comment on whether or not this is the fastest possible way to query both the dictionaries?**

```
f = open('merged_dict.tsv', 'wt')

f1 = open('d1.pickle', 'rb')
d1 = pickle.load(f1)

offsets = {}
for key in d1:
    offset = f.tell()
    f.write(key + '\t' + d1[key] + '\n')
    offsets[key] = offset

del f1, d1

f2 = open('d2.tsv', 'rb')
d2 = pickle.load(f2)

for key in d2:
    offset = f.tell()
    f.write(key + '\t' + d2[key] + '\n')
    offsets[key] = offset

f3 = open('dict_offets.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(offsets, f3)
```

Now when I need to query the dictionary, I do following :

```
f = open('merged_dict.tsv', 'rt')
f1 = open('dict_offsets.pickle', 'rt')

d = pickle.load(f1)

#query the dictionary using following function. 
def query_dictionary(key):
    offset = d[key]
    f.seek(offset)
    return f.readline().split('\t')[1]
```

I think the performance issue with storing dictionaries as tsv file is because of the values being numpy arrays. I need to convert strings to numpy arrays, which might be impacting the querying performance.

**If this is not the best way, someone please suggest the better approach for this. Once again, I'm highly concerned with the efficiency of querying. I want to get the value from dictionary as fast as possible.**

Comment: Are you sure you even have enough memory to hold the merged dictionary?

Comment: @MarkSnyder Ok, I get this. If it's not possible to store both dictionaries in memory, then it's also not possible to store the merged dictionary. But if I can query the merged dictionary on demand without loading it on memory, then It's really awesome.

Comment: Or do you have some other suggestion on querying on both of these dictionaries from a program? I'm also concerned about the efficiency of querying. I tried writing this dictionary as a tsv file, but I guess this might affect the querying performance. I stored line offsets as indices to efficiently read lines out of this file.

Comment: If the data being pickled is too large for your RAM then `pickle` is not the right format to use. A pickled object is always loaded at once and will raise a MemoryError then. Use a format that can be loaded selectively (CSV, a database…).

Comment: @KlausD., thanks for your suggestion. I used something similar you suggested. Look at the update I did in the question. But Is it the best approach for such problem? Querying dictionary is a lot more faster than seeking in a file position, reading a line, tab splitting it, and then returning a 2nd item.

Comment: Your question should not be to merge the two dictionaries, and then store merged dictionary in a file. Your question should be something about "Querying on two large dictionaries efficiently".

Comment: @RuchitVithani, yes that makes more sense. I'll see if I can change it.